# open message app with body ios url scheme

Tags: ios, sms, url-scheme

I'm trying to open the message app using the following statement:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:12345&body=some text here"]];
```

Everything is working properly on iPhone 5 and 6 which have iOS 8.x installed but on the iphone 4 which uses 7.1.2 it does not work!!!

Anyone can help please.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `MFMessageComposeViewController` instead. It seems that `&body=ZzZ` is a new feature and is not documented (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html), so maybe a new hidden feature in iOS8.

Comment: As I recall, this feature was already there. Do you know when they remove it? starting  iOS 7 ?

Comment: As Larme stated there is no official documenting on the body parameter for the `sms:` schema. Since there is no document we can not say when/or/if Apple removed it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then we can't know what is happening.

Comment: I strongly suggest you do not op the messages app but use [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will move to [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html)